# Log entity creation

Tags: symfony, doctrine, lifecycle

I want your help to solve a little problem.

I try to register log entity with the 'onflush' event. 
I have a working solution for create, edit or delete entity.

But now, I want to register id entity when a new object has been inserted.
The 'onflush' event doesn't manage id when he has been called by Doctrine Lyfecylce.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush

So i have try to work with 'postflush' event.
I have get id object, but i don't know how i can save this.

Here is a bit code :

```
public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::onFlush,
            Events::postFlush,
        );
    }

public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->log->setObjectId($this->element->getId());

        dump($this->element->getId()); // return element ID
        dump($this->log->getObjectId()); // return log attribute
// no data has been saved
    }

 public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        if (sizeof($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions()) > 0)
            $this->logEntityChangeSets($em, $uow, Log::STATUS_INSERT, $uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions());

        $uow->computeChangeSets();
    }

    public function logEntityChangeSets(EntityManager $em, UnitOfWork $uow, $status, Array $array)
{
// code for create Log entity and fill it
}
```

Thanks for your patience and your help.

Comment: it really depends on how you choose to save this audit track record. Will you do it in the same database? Or will you turn to a whole different stack for that, like `ELK` stack maybe?

Comment: Currently, i want to save log entity in same database.

Comment: In that case you are off to a good start, but just make sure you ignore `onFlush` for your `Log` entities (which will also pass through the `persist/flush` flow). Another thing to watch for is `DQL` executed queries - updates done in such manner do not go through entity lifecycle methods and thus will not be recorded

Comment: Ok so, after the onflush event, just update the last Log Entity with a DQL command for ignore the doctrine lifecycle ? I guess its not a good practice :/